# Speaking properly

Tags: single-word-requests, prepositions, terminology, slang, translation

How to respond when giving gratitude?

Comment: Gratitude for what? You'd respond differently when someone saved your life to someone simply holding a door open for you. You're specifically after a single slang word?

Comment: Welcome to ELU, but this site deals with the nuts and bolts of how English is put together and used, not how to use it in a particular social setting. Perhaps you're not asking for that; but in that case I'm afraid the question is unclear. Who is "giving gratitude"? (And that's a really unusual way of putting that.) For what? Are you really wanting *slang*? What does the "translation" tag have to do with this? While questions need to be short and succinct, they do need to include everything which would help the community give an answer. Please do [edit] your question.

Comment: Interpersonal Skills.SE is the related site dealing with polite forms of address etc.